# Ruby require_relative

Tags: ruby, require

This is incredibly hard to google for.  I have a file that is located in

```
/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/my_ruby_file_to_be_executed.rb
```

Inside that file I need to require this file

```
/folder_1/folder_4/file_to_require.rb
```

I cant workout how to write the relative path from one to the other.
I am using ruby 1.93

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `..` in your path will back you up a folder. So, if you are moving from `folder_3` back to `folder_2` and then back again to `folder_1`, you will need something like this:

```
# my_ruby_file_to_be_executed.rb 
require_relative '../../folder_4/file_to_require.rb'
```